# Windowbuilder - How do I show an array of JTextFields in the Design window?

Tags: arrays, windowbuilder

I started my Windowbuilder project layout using static JTextFields, but when I replaced them all with an array of JTextFields, they don't show up in the Windowbuilder design window. They do show up correctly only when I run my project. Is there a way to turn them on in the design window?